# Poco C++ libraries and Win32 GUI integration

Tags: c++, winapi, poco-libraries

Has anyone ever used Poco C++ libraries in a Win32 GUI application?
In the PocoFoundation library, many #undef inside the UnWindows.h header file, inhibit the use of important APIs ( as CreateWindows(), LoadLibrary(), and so on).
All right, I can define the POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS flag, but other problems arise.
Any suggestion is welcome.
Sergio

Comment: I just compiled Foundation with POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS defined without error. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: compiling PocoFoundation in windows with POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS went well.
I was trying to load PocoFoundation.dll dinamically with LoadLibrary().
POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS must be defined in the calling application or not?

Comment: No, it does not have to be defined.

Comment: FWIW, Poco has a [SharedLibrary](http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.SharedLibrary.html) class that can ease the task of loading a DLL. You can see the example on how to use it [here](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/testsuite/src/SharedLibraryTest.cpp#L41)

Comment: SharedLibrary is internal to PocoFoundation therefore
the calling application must load the PocoFondation
in order to use SharedLibrary, ClassLoader from
which you can access each module and class.
The possibilities, in my opinion, are three:
1) load statically PocoFondation
2) dynamically load PocoFoundation
3) compile SharedLibrary, ClassLoader and FileSysytem in the calling application without dependency.

Comment: I've lost you here - if you are not linking to Foundation in some fashion already, why this question in the first place? BTW, you do not need to call LoadLibray to load PocoFoundation.dll, it is done automatically when you include [Foundation.h](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Foundation/include/Poco/Foundation.h#L92)

Comment: Also, you should define POCO_DLL in the application, otherwise it will try to link static Poco library. As for POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS, to clarify the answer above, if you happen to include UnWindows.h from your application directly or indirectly, you may encounter problems at compile time when trying to call an undef'd API macro.

Comment: Thank you Alex. Sorry: I'm learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poco, as a portable library, is based on UTF-8 strings. Windows Unicode is UTF-16. For clarity purposes, it is recommended that all Windows API calls that take strings be called directly (i.e. A or W version), with appropriate string encoding and the conversion thereof, if necessary.

EDIT: Poco Foundation library can be compiled with POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS.