# How to get user name with Poco C++ library?

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Poco library don't allow to use GetUserName function. So, how to get user name with Poco library?

Comment: What do you mean with "don't allow to use GetUserName function"? I don't think that POCO can restrict the usage of Win32 functions...

Comment: In Foundation\include\Poco, you can find a file UnWindows.h, Poco undef some function, it include GetModuleFileName, GetUserName, ...

Comment: [From *Poco C++ libraries and Win32 GUI integration*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27845661/1287251): "Poco Foundation library can be compiled with POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS." You could also directly call `GetUserNameW` (utf-16) or `GetUserNameA` (ASCII). `GetUserName` is just a macro for one of the `W`/`A` variants. Poco just removes the macro and forces you to call the `W`/`A` variant directly unless you define `POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS`.